# How could I implement a xor operation of big integers with gmpy?

Tags: python, gmpy

I want to xor two big integers.
Just installed the gmpy2 library, but no mpz_xor operation anywhere.
Am I missing something?

Comment: I would expect it to just be `^` in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has operator overloading, so they just made it `^`. I would post a demo, but I only have access to gmpy 1.17, not gmpy2. Here's a [code link](https://github.com/aleaxit/gmpy/blob/eb4349df24605a7b10d5b14a1518c93f518598eb/src/gmpy2_mpz.c#L63) showing the presence of an `^` overload, though.